# Check if the digits in the number are in increasing sequence in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was working on a problem that determines whether the digits in the numbers are in the increasing sequence. Now, the approach I took to solve the problem was, For instance, consider the number 5678.

To check whether 5678 is an increasing sequence, I took the first digit and the next digit and the last digit which is `5,6,8` and substitute in range function  `range(first,last,(diff of first digit and the next to first digit))` i.e `range(5,8+1,abs(5-6))`.The result is the list of digits in the ascending order

To this problem, there is a constraint saying

`For incrementing sequences, 0 should come after 9, and not before 1, as in 7890.` Now my program breaks at the input 7890. I don't know how to encode this logic. Can someone help me, please?.

The code for increasing sequence was

```
  len(set(['5','6','7','8']) - set(map(str,range(5,8+1,abs(5-6))))) == 0
```

Comment: Does each digit have to be exactly one bigger than the last?

Comment: yes @JohnGordon

Comment: The accepted answer currently seems to fail for 78901.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice that !!.

Comment: Going from 9 to 0 is not an increase, no matter what your problem statement says. Badly worded question.

Comment: What about `12345678901234567890`?

Comment: @jpm. 'Badly worded question'. Those are the constraints. By keeping those constraints into consideration, I have to develop the solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply check if the number, when converted to a string, is a substring of `'1234567890'`:

```
str(num) in '1234567890'
```

Comment: simple and answers perfectly. Good job.

Comment: This fails, for example for `'901'`, which is increasing according to the OP's definition (`0` comes after `9` and obviously `1` comes after `0`).

Comment: @JörgWMittag No, the OP says "0 should come after 9, *and not before 1*", so 901 is no a valid increasing sequence because 0 should not come before 1.

Comment: This is so clever. +1

Comment: God bless that guy

Answer (score 3):

you could zip the string representation of the number with a shifted self and iterate on consecutive digits together. Use `all` to check that numbers follow, using a modulo 10 to handle the 0 case.

```
num = 7890

result = all((int(y)-int(x))%10 == 1 for x,y in zip(str(num),str(num)[1:]))
```

Comment: you can avoid the double `str`'ing and slicing by using `zip(*[iter(str(num))] * 2)` instead but I imagine that's got way more overhead for such use in this case anyway... just throwing it out there...

Comment: This would incorrectly return `True` for 78901, as the OP says "0 should come after 9, and not before 1".

Comment: @JonClements nice but in that case I would create a string beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the zip version, here is an alternative solution:

```
import sys


order = dict(enumerate(range(10)))
order[0] = 10

def increasing(n):
    n = abs(n)
    o = order[n % 10] + 1
    while n:
        n, r = divmod(n, 10)
        if o - order[r] != 1:
            return False
        o = order[r]
    return True


for n in sys.argv[1:]:
    print n, increasing(int(n))
```

Comment: `n, r = divmod(n, 10)`

Comment: thanks @thebjorn, amazingly, on SOI keep learning new stuff every day :)

Answer (score 2):

I would create a cycling generator and slice that:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

num = 5678901234

num = tuple(str(num))
print(num == tuple(islice(cycle(map(str, range(10))), int(num[0]), int(num[0]) + len(num))))
```

This is faster than solutions that check differences between individual digits. Of course, you can sacrifice the length to make it faster:

```
def digits(num):
    while num:
        yield num % 10
        num //= 10

def check(num):
    num = list(digits(num))
    num.reverse()
    for i, j in zip(islice(cycle(range(10)), num[0], num[0] + len(num)), num):
        if i != j:
          return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take that just looks at the digits and exits as soon as there is a discrepancy:

```py
def f(n):
  while (n):
    last = n % 10
    n = n / 10
    if n == 0:
      return True
    prev = n % 10
    print last, prev
    if prev == 0 or prev != (last - 1) % 10:
      return False

print f(1234)
print f(7890)
print f(78901)
print f(1345)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No string conversion, pure maths. Guaranteed to be much faster

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this question got me thinking of Palindromes and that got me to thinking of this in a different way.

```
5   6   7   8
8   7   6   5
-------------
13  13  13  13

9   0   1
1   0   9
---------
10  0   10


9   0   1   2
2   1   0   9
-------------
11  1   1   11
```

And that leads to this solution and tests.

```
pos_test_data = [5678, 901, 9012, 9012345678901]
neg_test_data = [5876, 910, 9021]

def monotonic_by_one(n):
    fwd = str(n)
    tgt = ord(fwd[0]) + ord(fwd[-1])
    return all([ord(f) + ord(r) in (tgt, tgt - 10) for f, r in zip(fwd, reversed(fwd))])


print("Positive: ", all([monotonic_by_one(n) for n in pos_test_data]))
print("Negative: ", all([not monotonic_by_one(n) for n in neg_test_data]))
```

Results:

```
Positive:  True
Negative:  True
```

Instead of using to full list comprehension you could use a for loop and bail out at the first failure.  I'd want to look at the size of the numbers being checked and time somethings to decide which was faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this, a little verbose for readability:

```
seq = list(input())
seq1 = seq[1:]
seq2 = seq[:-1]

diff = [x-y for x,y in zip([int(x) if int(x)>0 else 10 for x in seq1],[int(x) if int(x)>0 else 10 for x in seq2])]

if any (t != 1 for t in diff) :
    print('not <<<<<')
else :
    print('<<<<<<')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that checks the next number in the sequence and then using `current_number + 1 == next_number` to detect sequence.

```
import bisect

def find_next(x, a):
  i = bisect.bisect_right(x, a)
  if i:
    return x[i]
  return None

def is_sequence(x):
  ans = True
  for i in x[:-1]:
    next_num = find_next(x, i)
    if next_num and i+1 != next_num:
      ans = False
      break
  return ans

print(is_sequence([1,2,3,4])) # True
```